# CKEditor 4 and Zend: Updating to CKEditor 4?

Tags: php, zend-framework, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I have an existing application that uses `CKEditor 3` with `Zend`. I have been using `Zend_Form_Element_Textarea` to create the textArea and have set the class attribute to `editor_normal`.

```
$content = new Zend_Form_Element_Textarea('editor_normal');
        $content->setLabel('Edit:')
                ->setAttrib('cols', 50)
                ->setAttrib('rows', 8)
                ->setAttrib('class','basic')
                ->setRequired(TRUE);
        $this->addElement($content);
```

I have added ckeditor to the head script, in the page controller init function:

```
$this->view->headScript()->appendFile($this->view->baseUrl('/library/ckeditor/ckeditor.js'));
```

I create the objects with

```
$view->ckeditor();
```

In the a javascript tag:

I set the configuration for CKEditor and then use:

```
jQuery('.editor_normal').ckeditor(tool);

//tool is a custom toolbar
However, I am led to believe that the class file: ckeditor.php is no longer included as of CKeditor 4 so I removed all of the view->ckeditor(); and jQuery('.editor_normal').ckeditor(compact); and have added:

window.onload = function() {
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor_normal, {
    toolbar: 'Basic',
    uiColor: '#9AB8F3',
    language: 'en',
    disableNativeSpellChecker: false,
    filebrowserWindowWidth: '600',
    filebrowserWindowHeight: '300',
    filebrowserBrowseUrl : '/mybrowse',
    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : '/myimages',
    filebrowserLinkBrowseUrl : '/mylinks',
    filebrowserUploadUrl : '/myupload'
});
```

in the javascript of the page.

Unfortunately this does not work, is there a particular best practise to use when using it with zend, and am I missing something out in my workflow?

When I copy the source of the outputted zend page and paste that into a normal html file and host it on a server it works.
Thank you

Javascript Console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < loadck.js:1
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addCss' css-refresh.js:39
```

Comment: Can you show your debug console (Javascript) ?

Comment: console included, I redid the changes I made and then refreshed the page and it worked to my surprise. I refreshed again and it has stopped and hasn't worked since...unbelievable